# Entity Framework Core not returning expected results when using `Include` and `Contains`

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core application that uses Entity Framework Core to interact with a SQL Server database. I have a specific issue where I'm unable to retrieve the expected results when using the `Include` method along with `Contains` in a `Where` clause.

Here's the method I'm using in my repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Course>> GetAll(string searchString)
{
    var courses = await _db.Courses
        .Include("Subcategory")
        .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchString))
        .ToListAsync();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        courses = courses
            .Where(c => c.Subcategory.FullDescription.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))
            .ToList();
    }

    return courses;
}
```

In this method, I'm trying to load all Course entities from the database, including the related Subcategory for each Course. Then, if a searchString is provided, I want to filter the results to only include Course entities where the FullDescription of the related Subcategory contains the searchString.

However, when I pass a string to this method, it returns an empty list even though there are matching records in the database. For example, if I pass the string "test" to this method, and there are Subcategory entities in the database with a FullDescription that contains "test", the method still returns an empty list.

I've tried debugging the method and confirmed that the Include call is correctly loading the related Subcategory entities, but the Contains call doesn't seem to be filtering the results as expected.

I've searched for similar issues and found some questions about the Include method and the Contains method, but none of them seem to address this specific issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I attempted to retrieve a list of `Course` objects from my database that match a specific `searchString` in their `Subcategory`'s `FullDescription` field. I used Entity Framework Core's `Include` method to load the related `Subcategory` objects, and the `Contains` method in a `Where` clause to filter the results based on the `searchString`.

I expected the `GetAll` method to return a list of `Course` objects that have the `searchString` in their `Subcategory`'s `FullDescription`. I also expected the `Subcategory` property of each `Course` object to be populated with the corresponding `Subcategory` object from the database.

However, the method returned an empty list, indicating that no matches were found. Additionally, when I debugged the code, I noticed that the `Subcategory` property of the `Course` objects was null, suggesting that the `Include` method did not work as expected.

Comment: That does sound weird. Have you tried the Lambda `.Include(x => x.Subcategory)`? Also check the database connection string with `_db.Database.GetConnectionString()` (I think that is the current EF Core method, it has changed a couple times) To verify that at runtime you are going to the database you expect.

Comment: in principle (I think) you don't need include. Just provide your criteria `.where( c => c.subcategory.fulldescription.tolower().contains(searchString))` The code you posted would clearly only take records where the course name contains search string, which seems different from what you say you wanted to do.

Comment: Just check the generated sql query by EF and then you will find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected the GetAll method to return a list of Course objects that
> have the searchString in their Subcategory's FullDescription. I also
> expected the Subcategory property of each Course object to be
> populated with the corresponding Subcategory object from the databa

Well, based on your Scenario, shared code snippet, description I have tried to similate your issue. However, your code shippet were correct and working as expected. As you can see below:

[image]

[image]

> I've tried debugging the method and confirmed that the Include call is
> correctly loading the related Subcategory entities, but the Contains
> call doesn't seem to be filtering the results as expected.

Well, as per my investigation and test I have couple of fidings, while using [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0) built-in method your search string must have similar characters same as your containing database entity value.

For instance, say, your database containing the value of "Sub Cat B- SQL Database Language" as full description and if the Course Name has SQL then you would get expected result set. That's mean, either of your database entity column should have `SQL` within the containing text. You can refer below picture:

[image]

[image]

Therefore, please check your entity mappings along with the value within Course and Subcategory entity/class.

In addition, I have following entity/class:

```
public class Courses
    {
        [Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string? CourseName { get; set; }
        public Subcategory? subcategory { get; set; }
    }



public class Subcategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? SubCatName { get; set; }
        public string? FullDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Db Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
     
        public DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(string searchString)
        {
           
            var courses = await _db.Courses
                .Include("subcategory")
                .Where(c => c.CourseName.Contains(searchString))
                .ToListAsync();

       

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                courses = courses
                    .Where(c => c.subcategory.FullDescription.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))
                    .ToList();
            }



            return Ok(courses);
        }
```

**Note:** I have slidely modified the return type as I prefer `Task<IActionResult>`. Feel free to modify as per your requirement. I got the correct and expected result.

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wanted to take a moment to express my sincere gratitude for the time and effort you put into answering my question on StackOverflow. Your insights and guidance were incredibly helpful and allowed me to resolve the issue I was facing.

Your expertise and willingness to help others in the programming community is greatly appreciated. I learned a lot from your response and it has positively impacted my project.

Thank you once again for your valuable contribution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, glad to hear that your issue has been resolved.